# Angular 6 + keycloak 4, Javascript Libraries fail to load

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak

After successfully integrating keycloak with angular the token is received and the profile data returned. However "some" javascript features do not work. There are no errors in the console and the network information seems to be fine. If I am suppose to remove the provider information from the AppModule, the page loads fine but once keycloak is called the toggle feature on the page does not work or the loader loads indefinitely. If I comment out the loader the page comes up but features like toggling the menu does not work. I am Not sure if anyone has encountered this issue when integrating keycloak with angular and can guide me to how to resolve this.

AppModule

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent
       ],
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule
    ],
    providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
   } 
 ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Initializer function

```
export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
return () => 

             keycloak.init({
                config: environment.keycloak,
                initOptions: {
                    onLoad: 'login-required',
                    checkLoginIframe: false
                }
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log("Error thrown in init "+e)
            });
```

HTML - I changed the href for `app-side-mini-toggler` to routerLink. If not the click would just redirect to localhost:4200/#, instead of toggling

```
<div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-4">
 <a class="mini-nav-btn" routerLink="#" id="app-side-mini-toggler">
                    <i class="icon-menu5"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#app-side" data-toggle="onoffcanvas" class="onoffcanvas-toggler" aria-expanded="true">
    <i class="icon-chevron-thin-left"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

[With Loader, Page loads infinitely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMNka.png)

[Without Loader Page loads with user information but menu toggle does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgXID.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible Keycloak is overwriting some Javascript functions, has certain dependencies, or only works in a specific version of Angular.

Perhaps this library could be useful for you: https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular

Comment: Interestingly, I have used that github tutorial as well to integrate keycloak. However, still having the problem but you maybe right keycloak-angular library seems to be overiding some of my javascript functionalities.